# Java JDBC getting old values after deleting and inserting new rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a table with more than 7 million of rows in mysql (InnoDB) and I do some operations with Java. Everything was working correctly until I had to delete some rows and insert some new rows.

The problem is that when I do a select, I keep getting the old values instead of the news. For example if I try to do a count(*), I get 2760, instead of 2786.

Any idea?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: feels like a transaction problem to me. is auto commit off?

Comment: maybe you should `commit` your delete and insert queries first, if there's no autocommit.

Comment: Either a missing commit or the effects of the `repeatable read` default isolation level. Run a `commit` (or `rollback`) in the tool you use to verify the data before running the select to make sure you have ended *that* transaction.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I am facing issue because of repeatable read. Can you write an answer to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check in the Database options, if the db have the auto-commit option selected.

If auto-commit isnt possible, make a db.commit() after each transaction and make your transaction class synchcronized (for safe reasons).

Answer (score -1):

use `count(id)` instead of `count(*)` where id is your primary key of your table because for count rows `count(id)` is preferable over `count(*)`

And you should mention exact problem so that we can easily solve it so provide some situation where you stuck

Comment: If `id` is the primary key, then there is absolutely no difference between `count(id)` or `count(*)` and neither of them is faster or behaves differently than the other in that case. And in no case does this answer the question.